# How to load grayscale image as numpy array in openCV

Tags: python, opencv

i have the 96x96 pixel image as numpy array. The thing is i dont know how to make opencv load this ndarray and detect faces.

```
img = cv2.imread(X)
```

This line does not work. i get this error

```
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, numpy.ndarray found
```

X is the input image array (grayscale)

Comment: imread expects a filename. if X is a numpy array already, why not use it as is ?

Comment: Thats what i did and it is throwing the above error.

Comment: then you will have to show us the *that* code.

Answer (score 0):

ok it works now using this

```
img = X[k].reshape(96,96)
```

but the i opencv shows black images when outputting. As requested this is the piece of code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, cv

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
from skimage import transform
from numpy import ravel

import pylab as pl

from sklearn import linear_model, cross_validation
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.neural_network import BernoulliRBM
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

df = pd.read_csv('/users/prabhubalakrishnan/Desktop/training.csv', header=0)

x = df['Image'][:5].values


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

X = []

for k in xrange(len(x)):
    img = np.fromstring(x[k], dtype = np.uint8, sep=' ', count=96*96)
    X.append ( ravel(transform.resize (img.reshape(96,96) , (96,96))) )

'''
for k in xrange(len(X)):
 pl.imshow(X[k].reshape(96,96),cmap=pl.cm.gray)
 pl.show()
'''

X = np.array(X)
X = X.astype('uint8')

print 'X:', X.shape, X.dtype

pl.ion()


for k in xrange(len(X)):

    img = X[k].reshape(96,96)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.03, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
     cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
     roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    print 'Image',img
    print 'Faces',faces
    cv2.namedWindow("img", cv2.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```